# Can we say that $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f_i(t)\to 0 }~~\text{a.e}$?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(E,\mathcal {A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence bounded in $L^1$, such that:
$$
f_n(t)\to 0 ~~\text{a.e and in } L^1
$$

Can we say that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f_i(t)\to 0 }~~\text{a.e}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's [Cesàro convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation). Wherever $f_n\to0$ pointwise, you'll have that $\tfrac1n\,\sum_{j=1}^nf_j\to0$ pointwise.